# What properties of dark matter can we derive from each of the available methods for probing the physics of dark matter?

Tags: cosmology, dark-matter, beyond-the-standard-model, large-hadron-collider

This is probably a long shot but it's worth trying. My question is the following:

What properties of dark matter can we derive from each of the available methods for probing the physics of dark matter?

To elaborate a bit, my understanding is that the evidence for dark matter comes from its gravitational effects on large scale structures and from precision measurements on cosmological observables (e.g. CMB temperature anisotropies). The former method provides information about the structure formation of DM (e.g. DM halos) as well as that it interacts gravitationally with baryonic matter. The latter provides us with the relic density of DM which is around 0.26. What other properties can we derive from this kind of observations? (How do we know that DM is cold for instance?)

In addition to these methods, there are also direct, indirect and collider searches that aim in detecting signals from DM particles -- based on different principles and physical phenomena. Now, given that we eventually have a significant signal from these experiments, what can we learn from each type of experiment? Are all these methods able to give the mass of a DM particle for instance?

I 've read several papers and reviews on these methods and managed to get some answers, but any further insight (or recommendation) would be extremely helpful! Ideally what I am looking for is a table showing what kind of information can be derived by each method. Thanks!

Comment: One important observation not mentioned is the bullet cluster collision which is used to argue the case for a lack of self-interaction amongst dark-matter.